# How to access "Date" attribute of a file in Windows Explorer programatically

Tags: c#, windows

In windows file explorer, there is an option to sort the files based on a tab named *Date*. I would like to get that date information of a file in code (C#).

(This is different from the dates *Last modified* and *Created*, and also from the date provided by the `File.GetLastWriteTime()` method.)

How is it possible?

Comment: The category in Explorer is labeled "Date modified", and it does in fact correspond to the `File.GetLastWriteTime` method. How are you getting different dates?

Comment: @CodyGray There actually is a "Date" column too, but it's not shown by default I think.

Comment: Looks to me like "Date" is the creation date. The question could be a lot clearer. Perhaps the discrepancy is one of local time vs UTC time? We shouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` column compares creation and modification date and returns the earlier of those two. Even though there's no direct way to get that using the File class, you can just do the comparison yourself and use the earlier value.

Here's an easy (although not very readable) way to get the earlier of two dates:

```
new DateTime(Math.Min(yourFile.GetCreationTime().Ticks, yourFile.GetLastWriteTime().Ticks))
```

Here's also a screenshot that shows `Date` column always being the earlier one of `Date modified` and `Date created`.
[image: Date column differences]

**Edit:** The reason for modification date being earlier than the creation date is that the files in my example have just been unzipped from a zip archive.

Comment: The mind boggles at how the modification date could ever be earlier than the creation date. Perhaps you meant that it chooses the *most recent* (i.e., later) of the two?

Comment: It's certainly possible when dealing with archives. I forgot to mention that the files in my screenshot have just been uncompressed to disk from a zip file.